# Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached angular

Tags: angular, linux, inotify

I am getting this error while doing my Angular 10 project.

> `Error from chokidar (/myProject): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/myProject/tsconfig.spec.json'`

Is there a method to resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like you got too many file watchers running?

Comment: Can I do something to shut them down?

Answer (score 122):

You're running into a kernel limit with your inotify watchers. You can run this to fix it for the current boot,

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

You can run this to fix it for future boots,

```
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" \ 
  | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Yes and don't forget to reboot your Linux desktop.

Comment: I increased mine to 600000, still new files on save are not triggering server restart.Any suggestion

Comment: For those who copy-pasted the second snippet of code and got an error, just remove \ and make it a one-liner.

Comment: can we have solution to reduce file watch instead of increase system watch limit?

Answer (score 21):

I got this in vs code when doing ssh. I think the problem was that vs code was watching all the files in my node_modules folder. To solve this in vs code I went to:

File > Preferences > Settings, and then to the little paper icon at the top of the settings page. This takes you to the settings.json file vs code uses. Then I added this to the settings file and it solved the problem:

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/**": true,
    "**/samples": true
},
```

Comment: This is the solution to take.

Comment: "files.exclude": {
        "**/build": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    }

Comment: I've that configuration on vscode and for some reason it keeps looking at it. I would believe if the default setting now.

Comment: increasing `max_user_watches` just hangs up my system. Thanks man

Answer (score 14):

I found this post and helped me to solve that problem. All you have to do is change the max_user_watches

[Error ENOSPC System limit for number of file watchers reached](https://klequis.io/error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached/)

Answer (score 8):

**# insert the new value into the system config**

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

**# check the new applied value **

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Answer (score 7):

Use below

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

To increase the number of watches by your system

Answer (score 3):

watching many files can result in a lot of CPU or memory usage. so increase the number of file watcher if you really needed.

Here's how to optimize file watching using Webpack and TypeScript configurations:

### Using Webpack

if you **use webpackJs** then we can exclude some files or folders to put it in file watcher using set some ignore file path in `webpack.config.js`.

> webpack.config.js

```js
// webpack.config.js
// try below option for exclude the Node Module folder from File Watcher
module.exports = {
  //...
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: '**/node_modules',
    
    // for multiple file path, declare paths as array element
    // ignored: ['**/files/**/*.js', '**/node_modules'],
  },
};
```

```
// In addition, you can specify an absolute path:
watchOptions: {
    ignored: [path.posix.resolve(__dirname, './ignored-dir')],
},
```

For More details [see this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored)

---

### Using TsConfig

we can exclude some files or folders to put it in file watcher using set `excludeDirectories` and `excludeFiles` options inside `watchOptions` option of tsconfig.json file. (only for --watch. it might not works for `ng serve` command without --watch option)

> tsconfig.json

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  // Some typical compiler options
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
    // ...
  },
  // NEW: Options for file/directory watching
  "watchOptions": {
    // Use native file system events for files and directories
    "watchFile": "useFsEvents",
    "watchDirectory": "useFsEvents",
    // Poll files for updates more frequently
    // when they're updated a lot.
    "fallbackPolling": "dynamicPriority",
    // Don't coalesce watch notification
    "synchronousWatchDirectory": true,
    
    // Finally, two additional settings for reducing the amount of possible
    // files to track  work from these directories
    "excludeDirectories": ["**/node_modules", "_build"],
    "excludeFiles": ["build/fileWhichChangesOften.ts"]
  }
}
```

For More details [see this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vscode you can just reload current window by pressing the shortcut `shift` `+` `Ctrl` + `p` and then type Reload window. According to vs code this will

> Process re-connection: When reloading a window (for example, after installing an extension), reconnect to the previous process and restore its content.
> Process revive: When restarting VS Code, a terminal's content is restored and the process is relaunched using its original environment.

For more reference of this refer to this [Terminal Advanced Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#:%7E:text=Process%20reconnection%3A%20When%20reloading%20a,relaunched%20using%20its%20original%20environment.)