# (Angular) Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a project in angular but when I try to compile it shows me these errors over and over till my IDE closes.

```
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers 
reached, watch '/home/pedro/Universidad/Vacas-Dic2021/Archivos/LAB/MIA_Proyecto2_201709146_201900612/SoccerStatistics/node_modules/typescript'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers 
reached, watch '/home/pedro/Universidad/Vacas-Dic2021/Archivos/LAB/MIA_Proyecto2_201709146_201900612/SoccerStatistics/node_modules/typesript/lib'
```

I'm using angular 12 and node 14.17.6

Comment: Just one line command.[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71282671/14591547)

Answer (score 5):

If you can not increase the size of the watch (fs.inotify.max_user_watches), you can still compile angular using this command :

```
ng serve --watch --live-reload --poll 2000
```

Worked for me, and I am using virtual-studio-code as IDE

Answer (score 3):

Remove `node_modules` and reinstall packages

(Not the best solution because this bug comes back after restarting the computer)

```sh
rm -rf node_modules
```

```sh
yarn install
```

That does the trick for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command to resolve the problem.

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```