# VsCode Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached

Tags: visual-studio-code, inotify

How can I kill files watcher in VsCode without increasing `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` on my computer ? What is the correct pattern in settings for file watcher in the below example failing ? no matter the pattern it never matches **/srv/**

[image]

Related : [Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65300153/error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached-angular)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered the same ENOSPC error after `yarn install` and running `yarn dev` on my React web app repo
Then I updated the VSCode to 1.71.2 just now (21 Sep 2022), the error is gone

Comment: Hi thanks! I have the same version 1.71.2, it seems ```killall code``` kills watchers while ```killalll node``` does not. It seems to me a node isssue because I found a lot of occurences of the issue on twitter since 2019...